# Appwrite Random list of Documents

Tags: random, appwrite

I am currently working on Appwrite, and as part of my work, I am facing an issue. I would like to retrieve documents randomly. Is it possible to achieve that? Thank you.

I was trying through the use of limit and offset.
but not work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, unless you were to query using filters for specific ids, then you would need to know every id, or query for them all (looping through pagination for totals) then picking random from the list you built.